# check value true or false in @Html.CheckBoxFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm trying to assign `false` if value not available in Checkboxfor Helper

```
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsActive.HasValue ? Model.IsActive : false)
```

but still this showing error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'. An explicit
>   conversion exists

Comment: You cannot use `CheckBoxFor()` to bind to a `bool?` property (a checkbox has 2 states and a `bool?` has 3). Change the property to `bool` or use `EditorFor(model => model.IsActive)` to generate a dropdown list with the 3 values

Comment: I'll change property to `bool` then can I use as @Html.CheckBox(@Model.IsActive.HasValue ? Model.IsActive : false)

Comment: Then all you need is `@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsActive)` (a `bool` does not have a `HasValue` property - and its false by default)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the property to a `bool`, like Stephen suggested in comments, is the best solution for sure. *Recommended*

An alternative solution:

```
@Html.CheckBox("IsActive", Model.IsActive ?? false)
```